# Pull out the date and time stamp from notepad using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, date, time, stamp

```
XYZ Dispatcher Agent 'XYZ' is starting task '12821_1' at Tue Nov 12 01:01:49 2019.
```

Above is the first line in a log file I want to pull out the "Tue Nov 12 01:01:49 2019" in a variable using Powershell. I have tried using REGEX but facing issues with it. A logfile will always start with this kind of line so I need to pull out the date and time to know the start time of the task using this log.

Comment: For help with your code: *show* your code. Show any error you're getting too.

Comment: $paths= get-content "\\somepath\AgentLog_12821_1_12821_1.dsp.log"
$some = $paths[0]
$dateTimeString = [regex]::Matches($some, '(\w{3}/\w{3}/\d\{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}): ')[0].Groups[1].Value

Comment: Please [edit] your question. Code in comments is unreadable.

Comment: `$line = $Get-Content "\\somepath\AgentLog_12821_1_12821_1.dsp.log" -First 1`, then `$datetimestring = [regex]::Match($line, '\b\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}\b').Value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your files consistently have the format described in your post, you can do the following:

```
$regex = '\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}'
$firstline = Get-Content '\\somepath\AgentLog_12821_1_12821_1.dsp.log' -TotalCount 1 |
    Where-Object {$_ -match $regex}
$dateTimeString = $Matches[0]
```

The `$Matches` automatic variable is a hash table of values based on the previous ***successful*** `-match` result. It requires a successful match in order to automatically update the variable. You can `$null` the value.

---

If you want to capture all date matches in a file (one per line), you can use the following. This will capture all dates in an indexed collection (`$dateTimeString`).

```
$regex = '\w{3} \w{3} \d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \d{4}'
$dateTimeString = (Select-String -Path '\\somepath\AgentLog_12821_1_12821_1.dsp.log' -Pattern $regex).Matches.Value
$dateTimeString[0] # First date
```